# Inserting at front of a doubly linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

Here's my code to add a node to the front of a doubly linked list  .

```
public void insertFront(Object e){
        if(isEmpty()){
            head=new DListNode(e,null,head);
        }
        else if(head==tail){
            head=new DListNode(e,null,head);
        }
        else{
            DListNode tmp=head.next;
            DListNode v=new DListNode(e,head.next,head);
            head=v;
            tmp.prev=v;
            }
    }


public void addToTail(Object e){
    if(!isEmpty()){
        tail=new DListNode(e,null,tail);
        tail.prev.next=tail;
    }   
    else
        head=tail=new DListNode(e);
}
public String toString(){
    DListNode a=head;
    String result=" ";
    if(!isEmpty()){
        while(a.next!=null){
            result+=" " +a.item;
            a=a.next;}
        result+=" "+a.item;
    }

    return result;
}
public static void main (String args[]) throws UnderFlow{
    DList d=new DList();
    d.addToTail("a");
    d.addToTail("b");
    d.insertFront("c");
    System.out.println(d.toString());

}
```

Here's my DListNode class :

```
public class DListNode{
    public DListNode prev,next;
    public Object item;
    public DListNode(Object i,DListNode n,DListNode p){
        prev=p;
        next=n;
        item=i;     
    }
    public DListNode(Object i){
        this(i,null,null);  
    }
}
```

My question is after inserting to the front what it prints out is c,b not c,a,b.
What happens to the node with item a?Is it a problem with my toString method that it doesn't print out or is it a problem with insertFront().
I can't see where i am making a mistake.So any help to correct this would be really helpful

Comment: Corrected it.Though I wanted to insert before head i was inserting in the middle of head node and the next one.Why a was not printing was because of the line `head=v;`.I am pointing the new Node to be head and was removing node with item a from the list.corrected insertFront  which inserts at the head is:                     `public void insertFront(Object e){
  if(isEmpty()){
   head=new DListNode(e,null,head);
  }
  else if(head==tail){
   head=new DListNode(e,null,head);
  }
  else{
   head=new DListNode(e,head,null);
   
   }
 }`

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead

```
DListNode tmp=head.next;
DListNode v=new DListNode(e,head.next,head);
head=v;
head.next = tmp;
```